# How to remove subarrays with duplicated column value?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, unique

I have an array like this-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [size] => 12" x 24"
            [size_description] => <p>Rectified</p>

        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [size] => 12" x 24"
        [size_description] => <p>Rectified</p>

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [size] => 24" x 24"
        [size_description] => <p>Rectified</p>

    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [size] => 24" x 24"
        [size_description] => <p>Rectified</p>

    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [size] => 24" x 48"
        [size_description] => <p>Rectified</p>

    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [size] => 24" x 48"
        [size_description] => <p>Rectified</p>

    )

)
```

I want to get the distinct subarrays based on "size" and I can loop both the size and size_description. I have tried array_unique which is not working right, I am getting only one value that is size. What I tried is

```
$new_array = array_unique(array_map(function($elem){return $elem['size'];}, $size_array));
```

I want to get both the values. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I guess you could use [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)?

Comment: When you post array data on this site, always offer the `var_export()` output, so that volunteers don't have to reformat the data to use it in their tests.  Your question would be clearer with an exact expected output.  If the `size_description` values in your project data may be different, you should have crafted a more realistic question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `array_column()` to assign new associative keys using `size` without changing the subarray contents.  This is done with the `null` parameter.

Then just reindex with `array_values()`

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/1570L))

```
$array = [
    ['size' => '12" x 24"', 'size_description' => '<p>Rectified</p>'],
    ['size' => '12" x 24"', 'size_description' => '<p>Rectified</p>'],
    ['size' => '24" x 24"', 'size_description' => '<p>Rectified</p>'],
    ['size' => '24" x 24"', 'size_description' => '<p>Rectified</p>'],
    ['size' => '24" x 48"', 'size_description' => '<p>Rectified</p>'],
    ['size' => '24" x 48"', 'size_description' => '<p>Rectified</p>'],
];

var_export(array_values(array_column($array, null, 'size')));
```

Array keys may not be duplicated -- unique by force.

Comment: @AlWaqar Rakesh's answer will make _n_ function calls in the loop.  My solution makes a total of 2 calls no matter how big your array gets.

Comment: Thank you @mickmackusa for the help.

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the desired result

```
$newArr = array();

foreach($arr as $key => $value){

   if(!in_array($value['size'], $newArr))
    $newArr[$value['size']] = $value;

  }
```

Result:-

```
 Array
(
  [12" x 24"] => Array
    (
        [size] => 12" x 24"
        [size_description] => Rectified


    )

[24" x 24"] => Array
    (
        [size] => 24" x 24"
        [size_description] => Rectified


    )

[24" x 48"] => Array
    (
        [size] => 24" x 48"
        [size_description] => Rectified


    )

)
```

Comment: Thank you @Rakesh, your answer helped me a lot. But there is a better answer, so we must focus on quality.

Answer (score 1):

the code given by @Rakesh_jakhar is cool, but accessing by key is faster in php-array due it is stored as a hash-table:

```
<?php
$size_array = [
    ...
];

$new_array = [];
foreach ($size_array as $item) {
    if (!($size_array[$item['size']] ?? null)) {
        $new_array[$item['size']] = $item;
    }
}

$new_array = array_values($new_array);
var_dump($new_array);
```

and if you need to have an numeric array - use [array_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

[(demo)](https://www.tehplayground.com/zzFCDuU3RKZltjCT)